# SimpleXMLElement Object to Array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, object

I do not understand why when I echo this:

```
echo $HotelesDisponibles->Currency;
```

Results in "Mexican Peso".

But when I add it to an array like this and then print it:

```
$array_habitaciones["$HotelCode"]["Currency"] = $HotelesDisponibles->Currency;
```

It prints this:

```
[19243] => Array
    (

        [Currency] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [@attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [code] => MXN
                    )

                [0] => Mexican Peso
            )
      )
```

How can I transform it to:

```
[19243] => Array
    (

        [Currency] => Mexican Peso


    )
```

Greetings and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by adding (string) like this:

(string)$HotelesDisponibles->Currency;

But if someone could explain me why this fixes the issue I would be happy.